# Using a self-signed certificate

Tags: ruby, ssl, jruby, keytool

I am just trying to get my head around SSL.

I have set up a Jetty server on my localhost, and generated my own certificate using [Keytool](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/keytool.html).

Now when I go to https://localhost:8443/ I get the can't trust this certificate error.

I use

> keytool -export -alias pongus -keystore keystore -file certfile.cer

To create the certificate which I think is what the client needs to authenticate with the server. (This is where I could be very wrong!)

I have the following ruby code :

```
require 'net/https'
require 'openssl'

require 'open-uri'

puts 'yay' if File.exists?('certfile.cer')

uri = URI.parse("https://localhost:8443/")
http_session = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http_session.use_ssl = true
http_session.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
http_session.ca_file = 'certfile.cer'
res = http_session.start do |http|
  # do some requests here
  http.get('/')
end
```

This does print 'yay', so the certfile.cer file does exist.

But I get the errors

```
/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 6.8.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ruby2/jruby-1.4.0/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:586 warning: can't set verify locations
/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 6.8.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ruby2/jruby-1.4.0/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:586:in `connect': certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I want to get it so I guarantee that I am connecting to the right server, and the server can guarantee that it is me connecting to it, without any tampering in between. I am developing both the server and the client.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Your client needs access to its
>   private key.

You dont need the private key for server certificate verification. All you need is the certificate itself which contains the public key. Only the server has the private key. Well described here http://www.helpbytes.co.uk/https.php and here http://www.verisign.com/ssl/ssl-information-center/how-ssl-security-works/

My recommendation is simple. Check your certificate is correct.

```
openssl x509 -text -in mycert.crt
```

Also if you have access to the server you can explicitely validate if the certificate and key (used in httpd configuration) are correct (matches): http://kb.wisc.edu/middleware/page.php?id=4064 Please note this is explicit check ran on server. Never give out the private key. This check can be done only by the administrator to verify if the httpd was not misconfigured.

```
(openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in server.pem | openssl md5 ;\
   openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in server.key | openssl md5) | uniq
```

You can also debug the SSL certificate communication using standard openssl command. Issue this command then wait few seconds and then type QUIT and hit enter. You will see the certificate the server sends out.

```
openssl s_client -connect your.server.com:443
```

Also try to import the certificate to your browser and access the URL resource. Browser is able to validate it by clicking on https (Firefox and Chrome). Then you will see the certificate itself and validity information.

All the above was all about the **server certificate**. This is only one part of the problem. "*I am connecting to the right server*, and the server can guarantee that it is me connecting to it" Actully in your code above you only check for the server cert. Now. If you want a **client certificate** (the second part of your statement) than you need this in Ruby:

```
File.open( "client_certificate.pem", 'rb' ) { |f| cert = f.read }
File.open( "client_key.pem", 'rb' ) { |f| key = f.read }
http_session.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(cert)
http_session.key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(key, nil)
```

This is how **client cert** should be used in Ruby. If your private key is encrypted with a password just pass it instead nil in the second argument of RSA constructor.

I highly recommend to get server certificate working (your code) and then start with client certificate. Please note you keep your current code (ca_cert, validation constant) and add the above four lines to it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In any case you DONT NEED private key on your client. Never ever. Period.

Comment: One more thing. You can also EXPORT the certificate using Firefox or IE! Its very simple. Access the page and export it to a PEM file. You can use that one with Ruby. I did this several times. Works!

Comment: Wrong. You just don't understand SSL client authentication, which is what the questioner has clearly stated he needs. "...which I think is what the client needs to authenticate with the server..." as well as the comment in the edit indicate this.

Comment: No Greg, you are *not* right. He is *not* asking about SSL client auth but he is facing an issue with SSL server cert verifiation. This is different. Attributes http_session.ca_file and http_session.verify_mode are *not* for SSL client certs.

Comment: @Izap: You need to read what he wrote: "...so I guarantee that I am connecting to the right server, and the server can guarantee that it is me connecting to it,...". That is called client auth.

Comment: @GregS: It's possible that there's a difference between what he said and what he meant.

Comment: @Jumbogram: Agreed, that is often a problem here. You have to read between the lines sometimes.

Comment: Yeah, I missed the part "the server can guarantee that it is me connecting to it". Everything I wrote is still okay except "This is not true". He needs both. So in A he needs the server cert without the private key, B he needs a client cert including his private key (of course). Sorry for the confusion but I was pretty sure he needs only server cert (according his source code).

Comment: I have added client part to my answer. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your client needs access to its private key. The private key is not in the certificate, the certificate only contains the public key. Sorry, I don't know ruby, but a common technique is to bundle the private key and certificate in a single PKCS#12, aka p12, file and supply this to the crypto library.

Comment: Nice one, thats good information to give me something to go on! Ill go back to the keytool documentation. Thanks

Comment: Ruby does accept PEM. Theres no need for p12 and private key at all. Its a security hole to give out the PK :-)

Comment: @Izap: There is not a private key, there are two: one for the client and one for the server. That is why I said the client needs access to *ITS* private key, not the server's.

Comment: Greg you are trying to mix two things. The guy up there asked for SSL server certificate verifycation against CA cert. You are describing SSL user certification authorization. These are two different things. They can live together.

Comment: Sorry, he really needs a private key but only for a client cert. For server cert the private key is stored on the server. See my post above.

Answer (score -5):

Change

```
http_session.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
```

to

```
http_session.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

Once you do that, the SSL will work properly.  I have used this multiple times in my development environments, always works flawlessly.

Comment: Thanks, but I dont want it to sidestep verification. . ;-)

Comment: I'm sorry it took so long to respond to this.  As VERIFY_PEER tries to validate the cert against a known SSL issuer, you have to use VERIFY_NONE to bypass this check.  Its not validating the certificate per se, but validating the issuer of the certificate.  As self-signed certificates have no known issuer, it fails the check.

Comment: This is REALLY DANGEROUS. Dont do this if you dont know what you do.

Comment: it is ok for development/test only purposes