# Using Client SSL in a Ruby on Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, openssl, keytool

I'm working on an app for a client that requires an SSL connection with an API. I've been provided with three files; a trust root certificate (.cer) file, an intermediate certificate (.cer) file and a signed response file. The instructions I've been given to install this relate to either IIS or the Java keytool program; I'm building the app in Ruby on Rails so neither is an option (as far as I am aware).

The certificates are self-signed by the organisation who runs the API service and it appears I get given client certificates to mutually authenticate an https connection. I'm unsure how to

1. use the certificates in my application to connect and use the API
2. what the signed response file does

I've read ["Using a self-signed certificate"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123362/using-a-self-signed-certificate) and [this article on OpenSSL in Ruby](http://mathish.com/2011/01/14/openssl-in-ruby.html) but neither seems to quite hit the spot (and both have some reliance on Java/JRuby which confuses things).

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, the mathish.com article you linked doesn't actually have anything to do with jRuby.  The code I was demoing had to talk to an ActiveMQ message broker, which is Java based and uses Java's SSL certificate conventions.  The bulk of the comments in that code were there to remind me how to get Java's SSL certs out of a keystore and into a format OpenSSL would recognize.

Comment: If you open the .cer files in a text editor, do they begin with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` or something else?

Comment: Hey @ian, thanks for clarifying that. They don't begin with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`; no. Opening it with a text editor; it looks like the contents are encrypted in some fashion (just a random bunch of ASCII symbols and spaces etc, no legible letters).

Answer (score 4):

Based on your comments, I'm assuming that the certificates are in DER format, which you can convert to PEM with the `openssl x509` command (see: [openssl x509 command](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/x509.html)):

```
openssl x509 -inform DER -outform PEM -in certfile.cer -out certfile.pem
```

After that, you can instruct the Ruby OpenSSL library to use the trusted root certificate to authenticate the SSL connection with something like this:

```
require 'socket'
require 'openssl'

tcp_sock = TCPSocket.new("my.host.tld", 443)
ctx = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
ctx.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER|OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT
#You may need to specify the absolute path to the file
ctx.ca_file = "certfile.pem"

ssl_sock = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(tcp_sock, ctx)
ssl_sock.sync_close = true
ssl_sock.connect
begin
  ssl_sock.post_connection_check('my.host.tld')
rescue
  puts "Certificate host did not match expected hostname"
end
```

After that, you should be able to read and write to `ssl_sock` like any other Ruby IO object. If you are given a client certificate to use to allow the server to authenticate you, you can configure the SSL context with:

```
ctx.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read("my_cert.pem"))
ctx.key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read("my_key.rsa"))
```

before you create `ssl_sock`. The OpenSSL library also supports other key types besides RSA, such as DSA (see: [OpenSSL::PKey module](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/openssl/1.9.2/OpenSSL/PKey).)

Finally, a last piece of advice, if you are accessing a RESTful API, you may want to consider using a gem like [rest-client](http://rubygems.org/gems/rest-client) instead of handling all of the HTTP/S connection stuff directly. Whether or not such a library is appropriate or useful will depend on the service you are using, of course.

Comment: Just wanted to note that unlike the `ca_file` attribute on `SSLContext` objects, `cert` and `key` require the actual file data, not just the file name.

Comment: You also do not have to perform the `post_connection_check` and the surrounding `begin ... rescue` block if you don't care about verifying the name on the certificate.

Comment: Line 4 of the large code block should be `tcp_sock` instead of `sock`

Comment: Please move the rest-client suggestion to the top! Excellent piece of advice that saved me a ton of code!