# IIS Passing client certificate to rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, iis-7

I have an application written in Rails that must be ran behind a IIS server due to restrictions by the client, the government.  We have to have SSL authentication.  So what I can't figure out in my hours of searching Google is how to get IIS to pass the client certificate to the rails server (thin).

I've seen tutorials on Apache that use:

```
SSLOptions +ExportCertData
```

Which then make it available to the request object.  Any ideas on how to configure IIS to do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After being told this may be impossible.  I've finally figured it out!  Here are the steps that I took.

1. Using OpenSSL create your own CA certificate.
2. Using the generated CA certficate create and sign other certificates with Open SSL.
3. Open Internet Information Service Manager click on the server, then click on server certificates. [image: Server Certificate]
4. Click Import under the Actions column
5. After importing click on your site.
6. In the Actions column click bindings...
7. Click add, scroll to https, and select the CA certificate that you imported
8. Click on your site again to get to the menu and click on SSL settings
9. Check require SSL and then click the radio buttion, require
10. Click your site again then click on the configuration editor (installed in IIS 7.5 can add-in in 7.0)
    [image: Configuration Editor]
11. Go to system.webServer/security/authentication/iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication
12. Set enabled to true
13. Set manyToOneCertificateMappings to true
14. Click on the ... box on the far right-end of manyToOneMappings[image: Configuration Editor]
15. Click add under actions column, under collections
16. Add the username and password of the user you created (can be on local machine)[image: the ... box]
17. Now, go to the main server and restart.
18. You should be able to see the certificate using request.headers hash.

Variables for the hash include:

- CERT_SERIALNUMBER
- CERT_SUBJECT
- CERT_ISSUER
- HTTPS_SERVER_ISSUER
- HTTPS_SERVER_SUBJECT

If you cannot find something you may have to install a module (for like authentication).  I don't remember which ones I installed.

Answer (score 0):

At least in the way that you ask the question IIS cannot  provide a client certificate as the client cert would be issued by a third party.  So you need to get the x509 cert that your application and then the cert is authenticated as part of the initial connection request with iis.

As to the apache function to provide the ssl cert from the server to the client, this functionality is not exposed by iis.

That's why you were not able to find anything on google

Comment: The client certificates are issued by the government itself.  For testing purposes we have generated the certs.

Comment: I think you would need to access te certificate manually see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982421/using-client-ssl-in-a-ruby-on-rails-app

Answer (score 0):

The main reason companies want to run Rails(or Other) applications behind an IIS server is for SSO apart from protecting the resources.

See if this helps.

We have been running our Rails app behind IIS at quite a few customer locations. We run our Rails app in JRuby inside Tomcat.

The steps to install the JK ISAPI redirector plugin are here

```
http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html
```

All Rails contexts are protected in IIS using standard IIS authentication schemes, Integrated Windows Authentication ( Negotiate, NTLM).

Within the Rails app one can get the logged in user's information.

```
request.env['java.servlet_request'].get_remote_user
```

The Rails app also connects to Microsoft AD for additional user information like email, department etc.,

Since the Rails is blindly trusting the IIS server for authenticaiton it needs to be prevented from direct access.

```
1. Disable HTTP ports in Tomcat
2. Enable only the AJP port
3. Add an IP restriction so that it accepts connection only from the IIS server(s)
```

==
I do not think it is possible for IIS to pass on the certificate details. We tried to extract the Kerboros tokens ( for kerboros authentication delegation ) without much success and realized it is not possible.

Comment: This assumes that you are able to modify the IIS configuration correct? and if this is not possible?

Comment: Correct. There needs to be a web app added in IIS. Since IIS is the traffic gateway it needs to know what is behind it...for which it needs to be configured. That said no need to touch existing web apps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  The big problem with this is we have to get the government to approve everything we use with IIS.  So each additional thing that is required is kind of hard.